# How can i match 1 every 10 results using regex?

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

I have the following regex:

```
(^\[\s?.{1,15}\s?.{1,15}\s?\]\,$)
```

On my test file, i got 35k matches. I want to make a interval between the matches. In another words, "match" 1 every 10 matches.

Example:

```
[-51.039,-19.777], (match)
[-51.039,-19.777],
[-51.039,-19.777],
[-51.039,-19.777],
[-51.039,-19.777],
[-51.039,-19.777],
[-51.039,-19.777],
[-51.039,-19.777], 
[-51.039,-19.777], 
[-51.039,-19.777], 
[-51.039,-19.777], 
[-51.039,-19.777], (match)
```

Comment: This isn't something a regular expression can do alone easily. You're better off just setting a loop counter and only emitting a result every 10 iterations.

Comment: Or just use [`(^\[\s?.{1,15}\s?.{1,15}\s?\]\,$)(?:\s+^\[\s?.{1,15}\s?.{1,15}\s?\]\,$\s?){9}`](https://regex101.com/r/mhgU2S/1)

Comment: @horcrux Thank you! I used this and on replace field i used $1. Worked fine for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're OK with **capturing** every 10, it's simpler than you think (I assume). Try

```
(^\[\s?.{1,15}\s?.{1,15}\s?\]\,$\s?){10}
```

It simply repeats your regex 10 times (`{10}`). A repeated capture group captures only the last one. Note that it has to "eat" the line feed as well, so a `\s` at the en of the capture group is necessary.

Needs to be multi line, and using a global flag, it repeats until end of text.

[See it here at regex101 (capturing every third for better visibility)](https://regex101.com/r/cFusl4/1/).

Answer (score 0):

As @horcrux proposed i used the regex:

```
(\[\n.+\n.+\n\],\n)(\[\n.+\n.+\n\],\n){10}
```

And replaced by

```
$1
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you mean something like below regex (I don't see a reason to repeat a pattern like `\s?.{1,15}` except its limitation here).

Find:

```
(?:(^\[[^][]*],$)\R*){9}\K(?1)
```

Replace with:

```
ANY THING
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/gYE3Rj/1)

Comment: Hey @revo thanks for your answer. But i already [solved it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44910519/6860232)

Comment: Although you found a solution, a good practice is using a more efficient Regular Expression. Yours doesn't follow a performance-wise method. @VitorCaleffi